# How to local user login(PAM) with MySQL?

Tags: debian, login, mysql, authentication, pam

The MySQL server has already been configured and can be remotely accessed from the client.
The client is debian and has installed 'libpam-mysql'.
What additional settings should I set for the local user login, besides the settings below?

'/etc/pam-mysql.conf' configuration:

```
users.host              = 2002:123::1
users.database          = PAM
users.db_user           = root
users.db_passwd         = P@ssworD
users.table             = users
users.user_column       = username
users.password_column   = password
users.password_crypt    = 0
```

'/etc/pam.conf' configuration:

```
 pam     auth    required        pam_mysql.so    user=root passwd=P@ssworD ho    st=2002:123::1 db=PAM table=users usercolumn=username passwdcolumn=password      crypt=0
```

'/etc/pam.d/common-auth' configuration:

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_mysql.so
```